# How to login cookies enabled websites using curl command line tool

Tags: linux, curl, cookies, command-line, forms

I am trying to login to a website (http://uva.onlinejudge.org) using *curl* command line tool and getting this message:

> Session expired or cookies are not enabled in your browser. Please press "reload page" in your browser, and enable cookies in your browser. Please refresh/reload page before filling-in.

Though I am using **cookie 'engine'** in *curl*.

I use following:

```
curl -X POST -o out.html \
--cookie uvacookie \
--cookie-jar uvacookie \
-F "username=username&passwd=password&cbsecuritym3=cbm_1960b41a_27dc4118_2767514d402a00c7480d9497dd8dbef4" \
'https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login'
```

I have extracted and simplified the HTML form of the login page and login successfully using the *simplified form* from firefox.
Here is the form:

```html
<form action="https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&amp;task=login" method="post" id="mod_loginform">

  <input type="text" name="username" id="mod_login_username" class="inputbox" size="10" />
  <input type="password" name="passwd" id="mod_login_password" class="inputbox" size="10" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cbsecuritym3" value="cbm_1960b41a_27dc4118_2767514d402a00c7480d9497dd8dbef4" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Login" />
</form>
```

**What is the problem? How can I login and save cookies of my desired site so that I can explore it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem identified!

The HTML form must not be simplified. Login will be succeeded when the full HTML form is used.

The form bellow:

```html
<form action="https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&amp;task=login" method="post" id="mod_loginform" style="margin:0px;">
<input type="text" name="username" id="mod_login_username" class="inputbox" size="10" />
<input type="password" name="passwd" id="mod_login_password" class="inputbox" size="10" /></span>
<input type="hidden" name="op2" value="login" />
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="english" />
<input type="hidden" name="force_session" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="B:aHR0cHM6Ly91dmEub25saW5lanVkZ2Uub3JnLw==" />
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="loginfrom" value="loginform" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbsecuritym3" value="cbm_6d014498_5fb7509f_73f7153baaa7d545a091ca80411ca167" />
<input type="hidden" name="j9bec7c5b8b989a1feec6f95855aab890" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="mod_login_remember" value="yes" /> 
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Login" />
</form>
```

[formfind.pl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Chronic-Dev/curl/master/perl/contrib/formfind/) script can be used to find the post data field. As the login page use static post data, so the form have to update regularly.

This BASH script automatically update POST data and make a string to POST using curl.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#this is rough and made quickly

cookieFile="uva.onlinejudge.org_cookie.txt"

curlFunc() { curl -f -L -s --compressed $@ ;}


formData="$(curlFunc "https://uva.onlinejudge.org/" | grep -B10 'value="Login"' | awk ' \
    BEGIN{
        printf "username=uname&passwd=pass&Submit=Login"
    } 

    /type="hidden"/ { \
        gsub(/\r/,""); \
        gsub("^.*name=\"",""); \
        gsub("\" value=\"","="); \
        gsub("\" \/>",""); \
        gsub(":","\"%\"3A"); \
        {printf "\&%s",$0} \
   }' \
)"

#POST to login form
curlFunc --cookie-jar "$cookieFile" --data "$formData" "https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login" >/dev/null

curlFunc --cookie "$cookieFile" "https://uva.onlinejudge.org" | grep -i "logout" >/dev/null && echo "Logged in successfully" || echo "Failed to login"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The final curl command:

```
curl --compressed --cookie-jar ".uva_cookie" --data \
"username=uname&passwd=pass&Submit=Login&op2=login&lang=english&force_session=1&return=B"%"3AaHR0cDovL3V2YS5vbmxpbmVqdWRnZS5vcmcv&message=0&loginfrom=loginmodule&cbsecuritym3=cbm_4f91ddd4_48433724_f4574ec18b7b5d249835064c788445f4&j9bec7c5b8b989a1feec6f95855aab890=1" \
"https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login"
```