# Proper HTTP POST request to mimic submitting an online form (using HTML, cURL or python)

Tags: python, forms, http, curl, post

**Problem description:**
I am having trouble figuring out what is missing from my HTTP request to get to the next page after this form:
When I do this from my code, I land on a "welcome" page instead of landing on the expected one from Step 2 below:

1. **Step 1:** Filling it out with the following and clicking "Search" in a browser:
2. **Step 2:** I get to this next page:

I have looked up all form data being posted and did a simplified pre-filled form here, but clicking on Search in this case does not work:

**What I have tried**

- I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805588/how-to-login-cookies-enabled-websites-using-curl-command-line-tool) which advises against simplifying the form, but I believe I am doing this correctly: all the fields I am aware of are present, I simply change their HTML visualization (which has no bearing on what is POSTed).
- The jspSynchronizerToken field could be checked on the server side, therefore I already tried filling it out manually with a valid value retrieved in the same browser. This alone does not solve the problem.
- I have tried using the following cURL command, but this does not work either:

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0" \
    -F 'locale=en_CA' \
    -F 'jspSynchronizerToken=BzDQe5n2dIhV4LHKyqV_u341627003039920' \
    -F 'FORMAT=TXT' \
    -F 'SORTED_BY=0' \
    -F 'SearchType=0' \
    -F 'Search=String With Spaces' \
    https://www.sed.com/sed?locale=en_CA \
> ~/Downloads/sed.html
```

- I have also coded a more in-depth python version in which I provide the referer as well as the retrieved token from the Step 1, but with no success. (This code is available but it is simply a less readable version of the above simplified code so I don't see the point in posting, let me know if I am wrong).
- I have considered cookies and javascript might be the problem, yet a browser with no javascript or cookies allowed correctly submits the form and lands on the correct result.
- I am currently looking at the requests / responses using Charles Proxy, but I am not getting any new insights so far...

I realize this question is a bit specific to the website I am showing, nevertheless it seems to me that there is a generic understanding of how websites process HTTP requests and how to validly mimic those which could be gained by a proper answer here. I have had other experience akin to this one in the past and am hoping to understand this properly once and for all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a combination of errors in the strings, as well as copying/pasting the URL encodings from web dev tools. In particular, my strings with spaces should have stayed with spaces rahter than use the PLUS sign.